# How to restrict class access in Android library project on basis of key?

Tags: java, android, android-library

I have developed an android library having different functional modules. Any app who wants to use this library will have license key basis on that license key I have to restrict the use of other modules.

Say for Example -**XYZ SDK** with **1,2,3,4 module** now app who wants to use XYZ SDK for the only 1&4 module so according to license key will be generated, how can I prevent access to other modules (i.e 2&3 in above case)?

Comment: Have you tried any other sources to get started? It will be helpful to other for insights. Kindly add it here.@geek919

Comment: Do you want to prevent at compile time or runtime?

Comment: @UmaSankar runtime

Comment: It's complicated to explain in comment. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I get into the same situation, I will do the following.

- I will separate all modules and make them look like independent plugins (Refer Plugin architecture)
- I will share 4 separate dependencies and 4 license keys to clients, If I have 4 modules in my library
- On every plugin/module initialisation, I will validate the license key (either with server or store private/secret keys in android secure storage) and **store the result in a final variable**. If the license key is not valid, I  will not initialise remaining components in that plugin.
- For every public method in that plugin, validate the **license validation result** which you stored in final variable. If the validation is failed, just return with appropriate return type. This acts as a no-op even if they access your API.

In this way, you can control the access to modules/plugins at runtime.

If it difficult for you to split your library into plugins, you can follow the same steps which I mentioned above. You can also throw `IllegalAccessException`, instead of just returning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Design pattern and Following the Static factory method then, at the time of initialisation of your library create a method base on the licence key.

For Example If you want to give access to only two Library 2,3 then Initialise that two library in other two don't initialise so based on that whatever the functionality you want to give that you can define that one at initialisation stage.

- Follow this link if you want know about Static Factory Click [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA5&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false")